# PL/pgSQL procedures and transaction control

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, plpgsql

I'm new to Postgres, but with experience from Oracle. Trying to create a stored procedure which is going to:

1. Insert a row
2. Handle exceptions and in case of an exception insert a row into a log table by calling dedicated procedure
3. Emit an audit log record into a log table in case the whole procedure ran successfully

By pseudo code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test.p_insert(IN p_test_param character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        -- some declarations
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO test.a(a) VALUES (p_test_param);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                -- GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
                CALL test.p_insert_log(...); -- Inserts a row into a log table, another COMMIT may be required?
                RAISE;
        END;
        
        COMMIT; -- CAN'T DO

        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT test.f_debug()) THEN
                CALL test.p_insert_log(...); -- Audit the execution
            END IF;
        END;

        COMMIT; -- CAN'T DO EITHER
    END;
$$BODY$$;
```

However when I try to test the procedure out from an anonymous block in PgAdmin such as:

```
BEGIN;
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
$$
    BEGIN
        CALL test.p_insert(
              p_test_param => 'test'
        );
    END;
$$
```

I'm getting an error `ERROR:  invalid transaction termination`. How can I get rid of it? My objective is to let the procedure carry out the transaction control, I don't want the caller to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` anything. If I remove both `COMMIT` commands from the code of the procedure, it executes well, however the invoker must explicitly `COMMIT` or `REVOKE` the transaction afterwards, which is not desired. In Oracle the pseudo code with `COMMIT` statements would work, in Postgres it doesn't seem to work as I would like to. Could you please help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as intended. Perhaps you made some mistake in calling the code:

- you cannot call the procedure from a function
- you cannot call the procedure in an explicitly started transaction:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  CALL p_insert('something);  -- will fail
  COMMIT;
  ```